# Wrap HTMLCollection into a jQuery/Zepto function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, zepto

I wonder how I can successfully wrap a HTMLCollection into a jQuery/Zepto function.

I have the following same selectors: one in Zepto and the other in vanilla JavaScript wrapped around a Zepto function. The latter, though, doesn't make the Zepto methods available to its nodes.

```
$('#navigation a');
$( document.getElementById('navigation').getElementsByTagName('a') );
```

I'd like to make them equivalent.

Edit: I'm using Zepto instead of jQuery and didn't mention it assuming Zepto would behave the same way as jQuery.

Comment: So why not just *use* `$('#navigation a')` in the first place?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6jkWE/ . Looks like your problem is somewhere else (if there is actually a problem).

Comment: @DavidThomas, Part of my code is in pure JS and wanna make it compatible with my jQuery functions.

Comment: @FelixKling the jQuery methods are being added to the overall HTMLCollection but not to its individual children.

Comment: @Oriol: What do you mean by that? There is only one jQuery object which contains a set of elements. How are you trying to access/work with an individual element of that set?

Comment: Keep it mind that jQuery doesn't *add* anything. It's simply a wrapper around a set of DOM elements. The moment you pass the HTMLCollection to jQuery, it ceases to exist.

Comment: for example, something like this won't work: `$( document.getElementById('navigation').getElementsByTagName('a') ).hide();`

Comment: Yes it **does**: http://jsfiddle.net/6jkWE/2/. Since `$(...)` returns a jQuery object, *every* jQuery method works. As I said, the problem you are having must be something else. Passing an HTMLCollection to jQuery works perfectly fine. But without more information, we can't really help you. If `$(htmlCollection)` doesn't work for you, neither will anything else.

Comment: Alright, I've been using Zepto instead of jQuery, reason why it did not work at the first place. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6jkWE/3/

Comment: Yep, it really looks like zepto cannot handle HTMLCollections. In that case, convert it to an array first: `$([].slice.call(links))`. Also, `.filter` doesn't seem to work like this, you have to pass a function. Next time, tag the question with the library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following (untested)

```
var collection = document.getElementById('navigation').getElementsByTagName('a');

$().add(Array.prototype.slice.call(collection));
```

From the documentation of `add` (see [docu](http://api.jquery.com/add/)) this should be possible to add multiple elements to a current jQuery Object.

```
$( ... ).add( elements )
```

> One or more elements to add to the set of matched elements.

Comment: Thanks @Luke, I just hoped I could avoid constructing a new jQuery object but rather tweak my vanilla JS selection or wrap the jQuery function differently.

Comment: if you want to use jquery magic, you also need to assure that each object and the collection has a proper context and everything that is needed to wire everything up.